# "Use of undeclared identifier" in Objective-C++ when importing from another source file

Tags: objective-c++

I have declared a functions in a header file like this (pseudo code):

```
// funcs.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

NSString* func1();
void func2();
```

Then I have the implementations in

```
//funcs.mm
#import "funcs.h"

NSString* func1()
{
   // do something and use C++ functions
}

void func2()
{
  // do more
}
```

When I include the header in a third file

```
// AppDelegate.mm
#import "funcs.h"

....
string1 = func1();
func2();
....
```

Whenever I try to use these functions I get "Use of undeclared identifier" errors.

What am I doing wrong? Isn't function declaration in files in Objective-C++ the same as in normal C?

Comment: Do you have the real source code?

Comment: I am not allowed to post anything unfortunately. And plz bear with me I have nil experience with Objective-C.

Comment: Builds and runs fine here. Voting to close on the grounds that the problem is not reproducible.

Comment: I guess you should use methods instead of functions like:     -(NSString *)first{ return @"func1"};

Comment: I am just trying to split a huge AppDelegate into smaller more manageble files. These are just a couple of helper functions used just once. There are not classes.

Comment: @matt: Voting to keep this open on the grounds that you missed a crucial hint: It's a .mm file.

Comment: Ah, okay @gnasher729 - I retract my vote (cool SO feature).

Answer (score 0):

A .mm file is Objective-C++. Plain functions in a .mm file are not C functions, but C++ functions. Objective-C is the same as C, but you are not using Objective-C, you are using Objective-C++.

I would strongly recommend that you only use .mm files for interfacing with C++. For example, your AppDelegate should be a .m file and not .mm.

You need to write C functions like this:

```
extern "C" {
NSString* func1()
{
   // do something and use C++ functions
}
}
```

Also, in the .h file you should declare them like this:

```
#if __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
NSString* func1(void);
#if __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

The macro __cplusplus might be misspelled, google for it.

extern "C" tells the C++ or Objective-C++ compiler that a function should have C linkage.

Comment: Should I do this even if I use a header file or I should just skip the header file? And declare these as externs?

Comment: you can make your life easier by just using `FOUNDATION_EXPORT` instead of the preprocessor

Comment: Unfortunately nothing worked. That's a pretty big project that I have no control of (being the noob on the team). I was forced to give up splitting the file and put everything in the same .mm. Maybe the project is just too poorly set up I have no idea (I have no clue about Objective C and no time to learn it before the deadline). But that's good information and I'll try it out in my own project whenever I have free time.